# Simple storage variables saving after uninstall of add-on

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Can we store the simple storage variables after add-on uninstallation also?. I mean if the user undo's the add-on uninstallation, are they available to use. If possible how do that?

In my experience, simple storage is wiping after add-on uninstalling. But, they used again if the add-on is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

When user clicks "Uninstall" on the addon, the addon is "Soft uninstalled". So none of the "onUninstall" stuff triggers. Once they close the addon tab, then it triggers. The only time they can "undo uninstall" is while the tab is still open. (for restartless addons).

So have no fear. simple-storage will work be there on undo of uninstall.

Comment: I didn't get you. I don't have any tab or separate page from the add-on. If the user uninstalls the add-on from add-on manager (user still have the option to undo the uninstallation until the browser is closed). In this case how to store the simple -storage.